# Files With Spaces Are Treated As Seperate Files

Tags: find

How can I modify the script to not treat files with spaces as separate files?

```
thetime=`date +%Y-%m-%d_%H:%M:%S` #
for i in $(find . ! -name "*.filepart")
do
         extn=${i##*.} # save the extension of the file
                 mv "$i" "${i%.*}"$(date "+_%Y-%m-%d_%H:%M:%S.${extn}")
done

mv: cannot stat ‘./user1/upload/Axle’: No such file or directory
mv: cannot stat ‘Assy’: No such file or directory
mv: cannot stat ‘Removal.doc’: No such file or directory

#find . ! -name "*.filepart"
#./user1/upload/Axle Assy Removal.doc
```

Answer (score 0):

This won't work with files whose names contain whitespace:

```
for i in $(find . ! -name "*.filepart"); do   # Fail
```

The following two methods will work for all file names:

#### Method 1: Use `-execdir`

```
find . -type f ! -name "*.filepart" -execdir sh -c 'f=$(basename "$1"); mv "./$f" "./${f%.*}$(date "+_%Y-%m-%d_%H:%M:%S")${f#${f%.*}}"' Mv {} \;
```

#### Method 2: Use `-print0`

```
find . -type f ! -name "*.filepart" -print0 | while IFS= read -r -d $'\0' file
do
    d=$(dirname "$file")
    f=${file#$d}
    mv "$d$f" "$d${f%.*}$(date "+_%Y-%m-%d_%H:%M:%S")${f#${f%.*}}"
done
```

#### Further reading

[How can I find and safely handle file names containing newlines, spaces or both?](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/020)

Comment: Method 1 Worked Perfectly! I really appreciate your assistance with this!